# Sidebar falling beneath content and footer not 100%

Tags: html, css

I have no idea what is going on and can't figure out what is causing this.

This is the page in question: http://www.brandroot.com/resources

The sidebar is falling below the main content and the footer is not 100% across the page like the other pages on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your sidebar is inside the wrong element.
Now its inside the `<div class="left">`
and it should be outside, after that element.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too but I didn't touch the HTML, this happened while I was messing with the CSS. It was fine about an hour ago and suddenly this happened.

Comment: i think you should just put </div> above the <div class="right">. Inspecting the source codes indicates that you open 176 divs, but only close 175...

Comment: Another way is by changing the width of the .left div, since you mentioned that you were only editing the css.

Comment: I also checked and as @PeterVR said, you have 1 div less closed. check [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brandroot.com%2Fresources&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) last error

Comment: @trajce thank you, that corrected the sidebar, but do you have a solution for the footer not stretching across?

Comment: I figured it out, it was the missing closing <div>. I have no idea how that happened.

Comment: No worries, those things happen to everybody. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your "main" isn't big enough to hold that column. I expanded the width to 850px and reduced padding on the right column and it came up.

Generally, if you float something right, it's better to put that content, the div that is floated right, above the content it's floated next to in source order. Then you just have an overall width on the wrapper and then on the floated object. The rest takes what it needs.

Comment: You mean `<div id="main">`? Because the width of this is at 972px. Can you be more clear? Thanks.

Comment: sorry.... your div class=right is actually within the div with class of left. Move the div class=right out into your id of main

Comment: my suggestion also would be to move your right div into the main div. in case you cant, then check the widths of the elements inside. these are your widths. `#main width: 972px;` `.left width: 660px; + 20 padding-right` and `.right width: 291px;`